# How do I concatenate only if not null in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, sql-null

I have this table:

PersonTable

```
|  id  | name |
---------------
|  10  | Mike |
| NULL | Jane |
```

I want to select id and name from the table and use concat on id, but only if it's not null, like this:

```
+------+------+
|  Id  | Name |
+------+------+
| A10  | Mike |
| NULL | Jane |
+------+------+
```

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT ISNULL(concat('A', id), NULL) AS id, name FROM PeronTable
```

But my query returns this:

```
+-----+------+
| Id  | Name |
+-----+------+
| A10 | Mike |
| A   | Jane |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: A `null` in a column named ID is a very, very strong stink. Either a completely inappropriate name was used for a non-PK column, or there's no PK column at all, and the ID isn't an ID - the server won't allow a nullable column to be used as a PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.  You can use `+` instead of `concat()`:

```
select 'A' + convert(varchar(255), id), name
from t;
```

`convert()` (or `cast()`) is necessary assuming that `id` is a number and not a string.

`+` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`; `concat()` ignores `NULL` arguments.

Of course, you can use `concat()` with a `case` expression:

```
select (case when id is not null then concat('A', id) end), name
from t;
```

Comment: you probably mean '+' ignores NULL arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like the below code to get your expected solution:

```
Select 'A' + convert(varchar(255), id) AS id, name
from PeronTable;
```

Here is a sample screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `NULLIF()` as the following:

```
SELECT NULLIF(CONCAT('A', Id), 'A') Id,
       Name
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (10, 'Mike'),
  (NULL, 'Jane')
) T(Id, Name);
```

OR

```
SELECT TT.Value Id,
       T.Name
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (10, 'Mike'),
  (NULL, 'Jane')
) T(Id, Name) CROSS APPLY(VALUES (NULLIF(CONCAT('A', Id), 'A'))) TT(Value);
```

The function `CONCAT()` will returns `'A'` if the `Id` column is `NULL`, thus you need just to check if it returns `'A'` using `NULLIF()` function which will returns `NULL` if the concatenated string = A.

You could also use `CASE` expression if you which to as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TT.Value <> 'A' THEN Value END Id,
       T.Name
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (10, 'Mike'),
  (NULL, 'Jane')
) T(Id, Name) CROSS APPLY(VALUES (CONCAT('A', Id))) TT(Value);
```